# Can't pass variable to an element style prop React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`` <div style={{ width: `${stat.base_stat}px` }} /> ``

Can't get this to work, I ve made sure the property is not undefined but when I try to run thee app i get Cannot read property of null, Occured while linting, any ideas?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: We need more info about the stat object. To prevent the error, try to check if the value of the stat.base_stat is not equal to null.

Comment: Hi, `Cannot read property of null` means one and only one thing. That something is null. Post full code for people to be able to help.

Comment: Hi Gerard, if the linter says "Cannot read property of null" then the value is null. The issue likely lies somewhere else. Btw, you can pass your value straight into the object, without string interpolation and "px". React should infer that a number is a pixel. `{ width: stat.base_stat }`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to show how the `stat` variable is being initialized. Consider that for the very first render.

Maybe you are setting the value of `stat` after the first render.

Review the React Hooks flow (https://github.com/donavon/hook-flow) if you need.